# What does 「１０万円以下の所 」mean?

Tags: grammar

> 一日平均労働時間１６時間。月給なんと…３万８千円！日給でなく月給である。うちの病院の待遇が特別に悪いわけではない。国立ではもう少し高いらしいが、私大病院の研修医の月給は**１０万円以下の所**が約７割を占める。その給料で寮も食事もないんだから生活できるわけない。で…

I'm having trouble parsing the text in bold because of 所. My understanding is that it's being used figuratively to mean "section".

> 私大病院の研修医の月給は**１０万円以下の所**が約７割を占める。
>
> > *lit.* The monthly salary of medical interns at private hospitals takes up 70% of the section that is less than 100,000 yen.

Thus, the 30% is another "section".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this 所 refers to 私大病院. The sentence is the same as the following (bit clumsy) sentence:

> 私大病院の研修医の月給は、１０万円以下の病院が約７割を占める。

That is, among the hospitals attached to private universities, about 70% of them pay less than 100,000 yen per month for residents.

FWIW, junior residents are not assined to a specific section/department yet, so residents belonging to the same hospital will be paid equally. 私大病院 ("private university hospital") is very different from 私立病院 ("private hospital"). The average salary of the latter is usually much higher :)